# "installed" field not being returned by Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to get a value for "installed" when calling the Facebook API using their PHP SDK.

This is the code I am using:

```
$apiresult = $facebook->api("/$currentUserFbId/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture");

//print_r reveals that only id, name, and picture exist in the returned object
print_r($apiresult);
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is installed no `longer` supported?

Comment: Does `?fields=installed` alone work?

Comment: Nope, and it does not work if I leave out fields either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `installed` field only returns if it is true.  I would assume none of your friends have the app installed.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. I was thinking it would return installed=0 or some sort of value.

Comment: Actually, it probably will in future, it was changed recently to return 0 or 1 instead of nothing or 1 but it broke some apps so was reverted to the documented behaviour